# Summing datetime values from a flat file

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to sum then average time values that are stored in a flat file.
I am getting an error when I loop through time values.

**The error:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Not sure what the error is saying exactly since the values in the file are all in the same format.

**The file**

```
2016-06-03 21:53:48.658115      0:00:00.665788
2016-06-03 21:55:00.009529      0:00:00.867230
2016-06-03 22:09:46.813020      0:00:00.797387
2016-06-04 14:05:05.611144      0:00:00.721815
2016-06-04 14:08:09.029460      0:00:00.744576
```

**The code snippet**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
rowCtr = 1
for row in open('data.txt', 'rb'):
    date, response_time = row.split('\t')
    d = datetime.strptime(response_time, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
    dts = d.timedelta(hours=d.hour, minutes=d.minute, seconds=d.second, microseconds=d.microsecond)
    sum += dts # not tested
    rowCtr += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was \r\n (carriage return and new line) appended in the `response_time` variable which caused this error. So I used `response_time.strip('\n\r')`  to remove them. refer (1)

Then there was a timedelta attribute error came.

> AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute
>   'timedelta'

so I fixed that. refer (2)

Thirdly timedelta addition to be happened the variable `sum` needed to be initialized as `sum = timedelta(0)` on top. refer (3)

This is the working solution.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
rowCtr = 1
sum = timedelta(0) # (3)
for row in open('data.txt', 'rb'):
    date, response_time = row.split('\t')
    d = datetime.strptime(response_time.strip('\n\r'), '%H:%M:%S.%f') # (1)
    dts = timedelta(hours=d.hour, minutes=d.minute, seconds=d.second, microseconds=d.microsecond) # (2)
    print dts
    sum += dts 
    rowCtr += 1
```

Comment: Simply open the file in text mode by removing the `b` from `rb` and Python will [resolve the line ending issue](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: No it won't work. Then \n (new line) comes. again we have to strip('\n')